# Trying to update git, but comes up with error /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file git: Is a directory

Tags: git, version-control

Originally, I was trying to use Bitbucket which is a nice way to host code and so on. This uses `'git'`, the version control software, of which you can add code to from linux command line. However, when I tried to do this it came up with a bunch of errors.

So I did some searching around and came to the conclusion that `git` was out of date (it is version 1.5.4.3 whereas the most recent version is 1.8.1), so I tried to update using `sudo apt-get` and it says that it is up to date. I tried a few methods like running `sudo apt-get update` before hand without much luck. So I am now trying to install it manually. I successfully downloaded the tar.gz and unzipped it, but now it won't install and comes up with this when I try `make` (this is inside the git-1.8.1 folder):

```
    GEN perl/PM.stamp
    SUBDIR gitweb
    SUBDIR ../
make[2]: `GIT-VERSION-FILE' is up to date.
    GEN git-instaweb
    LINK git
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file git: Is a directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [git] Error 1
```

I found a blog post with a similar situation, but I don't really understand it:
[usrbinld-cannot-open-output-file](http://kmaiti.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/usrbinld-cannot-open-output-file.html)

So I would really appreciate some help with this!

EDIT: 
just tried `make clean` and it now comes up with this:

```
    GEN perl/PM.stamp
    SUBDIR gitweb
    SUBDIR ../
make[2]: `GIT-VERSION-FILE' is up to date.
    GEN git-instaweb
    SUBDIR git-gui
    MSGFMT    po/de.msg make[1]: *** [po/de.msg] Error 127
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you "sudo apt-get autoremove" to clean your previous install before compiling from source ? Maybe it's trying to link to the wrong shared object.

Comment: I just tried `make clean` and now it comes up with another error... will update question

Comment: Is this for Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: Never mind... I see your comment below... it's Debian.  If it was Ubuntu, you couled have done `add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`.  They've got updated packages for most of the Ubuntu distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that all the dependencies are installed, for example doing a `apt-get build-dep git-core`.

However seems strange to me that `apt-get` install a so outdated version, which version of Debian do you use, in Debian testing I have 1.7.10 installed.

BTW I use a [script](https://github.com/gipi/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/update-git-installation.sh) to update and install the latest version of git from the official repository.

Comment: in the etc/debian_version file it says lenny/sid. wiki says lenny is a couple of years old or something :/

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 6.5 x64:

```
export GIT_VERSION=1.8.5.2   # ie. the GIT version you would like to install
yum -y install openssl-devel.x86_64 libcurl-devel.x86_64 expat-devel.x86_64 perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker.x86_64 gettext.x86_64
wget https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-${GIT_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar -zxvf ./git-${GIT_VERSION}.tar.gz
cd git-${GIT_VERSION}
make prefix=/usr/local install  # to install in /usr/local
```